# Optaplanner make rows irrelevant

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to solve a planning problem. Is there a chance I can configurate a Move to make some values irrelevant?
e.g: The n Queen Problem: it doenst matter on witch row a queen is standing as long as it stands on the field.

Answer (score 0):

You'd get that situation if you remove all constraints from the `nqueensScoreRules.drl` - and add one constraint to define it's on the field.

In practice I can think of 2 models that do that:

- If the `Integer row` planning variable really is useless, turn it on to a `Boolean onField`. Then the constraint is obvious, it should be true. Though I doubt this needs a Solver to solve: it's easily solvable with a simple for loop :)
- If the `Integer row` planning variable is needed for other rules, then make it `@PlanningVariable(nullable=true)` and add a constraint that it should be not null. This is called "overconstrained planning" (see docs and PAS example).